# AWS S3 Bucket Policy with Empty Principle Array

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an old S3 bucket policy that grants full S3 access to a few principles. Upon editing the policy I recieved the error:

> Invalid Principle in Policy

It turns out that all of the principles within my statement were of the format, for example, `AIDADJFUT4RIFUGHRU7FU`.
Is this a removed account?

I removed all instances of these invalid principles, and now I have an empty array. I was planning on leaving this array empty for now, but I want to make sure that I am not accidentally leaving my S3 bucket open to the world.

Is the following policy secure?

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy123456789",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": []
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/my-directory/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why don't you remove the bucket policy completely and add it back when needed?

Comment: There are other parts of the policy which I have not mentioned above which are still in use.

Comment: If this is the complete part of this statement, delete this JSON. The statement part of the JSON is an array and this section can be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just simply leave the policy as is and change the Effect from Allow to Deny.

An open policy would require the Principle to be set as a wildcard: '*',   for example:

```
"Principal":"*"
```

or

```
"Principal":{"AWS":"*"}
```

These would make the statement open to the world.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you give more explanation on the current state -- is it open to all at the moment?

Comment: I think if you had an empty principal this policy will match nothing, so nothing will be the only entities with access.